# JavaScript to capture IP via WebRTC (issue with async/await)

Tags: javascript, security, webrtc

I have came up with code that capture IPs via WebRTC.
However I have run into issue, I can't return IPs as variable, I'm able only print IPs in console, show them in alert or show them on HTML page. But I need return IPs as variable from function.

I believe issue is in async/awaiting. I'm not JavaScript developer and it will took whole day to find out a place where to put `await`.

Please help me solve this issue.
Thank you.

```
function findIPsWithWebRTC() {
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}),
    noop = function() {},
    IPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

    function ipIterate(ip) {
        if (!IPs[ip]) console.log('got ip: ', ip);
        IPs[ip] = true;
    }

    pc.createDataChannel("");

    pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
        });
        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);

    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    };

    console.log("ips: " + JSON.stringify(IPs));
    return {
        "source": "WebRTC",
        "name": "IPs",
        "value": JSON.stringify(IPs)
    }
}

alert(findIPsWithWebRTC().value);
```

I can output IPs in console, but I can't return IPs as value from function.

[image]

Comment: The `.createOffer()` call is **asynchronous**.  It returns immediately; the callback function you pass is invoked later when the connection is established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findIPsWithWebRTC` **can't** return the IPs, because the IPs are provided to your code asynchronously. A synchronous function cannot *return* the result of an asynchronous process.

Instead, your `findIPsWithWebRTC` should return a *promise*, which will be fulfilled with the object your currently trying to return. It *looks* like you get the IPs in in `onicecandidate` (or perhaps the callback to `createOffer`?), so (see `***`):

```
function findIPsWithWebRTC() {
    // *** Return a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}),
        noop = function() {},
        IPs = {},
        ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
        key;

        function ipIterate(ip) {
            if (!IPs[ip]) console.log('got ip: ', ip);
            IPs[ip] = true;
        }

        pc.createDataChannel("");

        pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
            sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
                if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
                line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
            });
            pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
            // *** Resolve the promise? Or see below.
            resolve({
                "source": "WebRTC",
                "name": "IPs",
                "value": JSON.stringify(IPs)
            });
        }, noop);

        pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
            if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
            ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
            // *** Resolve the promise? Or see above.
            resolve({
                "source": "WebRTC",
                "name": "IPs",
                "value": JSON.stringify(IPs)
            });
        };
    });
}
```

Presumably there's also a way for this to fail. You'll want to call `reject` in that case, so that the promise doesn't stay unsettled forever.

Code using `findIPsWithWebRTC` will need to handle the fact that it provides a promise. You can either consume it within an `async` function:

```
// In an `async` function
try {
    const ipInfo = await findIPsWithWebRTC();
    // ...use `ipInfo`...
} catch (error) {
    // Handle/report error
}
```

...or in a non-`async` function, use `then` and `catch`:

```
findIPsWithWebRTC()
.then(ipInfo => {
    // ...use `ipInfo`...
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

In both cases, if the function consuming the result isn't the top-level consumer, you would normally leave error handling to it. In the `async` example, you'd do that by not having the `try`/`catch` (rejections are automatically propagated to the caller). In the non-`async` example, you'd do it by returning the result of calling `then` and not having `catch`.